# Multiple cams broadcasting service

Tags: webcam, broadcast

I want to set up three cameras at a wedding and stream them to the world. preferably so the viewer can see all three at once, but audio from one. I want to both broadcast live and save it to disk for later use. OS can be Windows or Linux. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use VideoLAN. Setup three streams, one stream for one camera and on different ports.

Comment: Can this be set to both capture and broadcast? I probably need a relay server of some sort since the cams will be on 3G connection, what I can I use for this?

Comment: With "on 3G connection" you're speaking about them being NATed? If you can send UDP outside, you could stream the video using UDP or RTP (_NOT_ MULTICAST) to a server outside the NAT. Theoratically VLC _SHOULD_ be able to receive the stream AND rebroadcast it using "more userfriendly" protocols. You need three instances of VLC on the server inside the NAT which connect to three VLCs outside the NAT, providing the server for the outside world.

Comment: VLC as such is an application originally designed for such purposes, but is quite flaky. It tends to crash for unknown reasons, whatever you decide to do, TEST IT.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Didn't know VLC could do all these things... I shall try it. Any quick hint on how to set it up on client + server? Also, can it run on a headless server, only terminal and no X installed?

Comment: I can't tell you about that, as I'm on OSX, but I'm quite sure it's possible to run it on a minimal system as I found VLC binaries on my NAS.